# Mystery gap at the top of a webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a website that is here:  http://www.southwoldholidayhomes.com/ and as you may see there is a ~25px gap at the top of the page before the content begins.

The original code / layout has been inherited from the previous web design company, and is not up to my standard but works well enough, aside from this issue.

I want to reduce this top-of-page gap, ***but I can't find what is declaring it***.

- I have set rules in place on the body / html elements to give margin/padding of zero.
- I have viewed various similar questions on SO which all seem to state it is setting of the margin/padding as per point one. I do not see that this is the cause, in this case.
- FireBug can not select that area of the screen but does confirm my DIV, Body and HTML elements have padding/margin of zero.
- The Gap is cross browser appearing on Chrome, Firefox and IE (so it's not a firebug / firefox specific issue)
- I have removed various hidden elements such as `<script>` for google analytics at the top of the page and `<div>` for microdata content at the top of the page, but these do *not* change this layout issue.

Below is the CSS and HTML layout in a slightly simplified form. The page layout does use lightbox but that CSS does not appear to interfere with the page layout CSS which is in a single file.

### CSS

```
html {
        margin: 0 !important; ///used for problem solving, not on original.
}
body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #111F35;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:400;
    /*line-height: 1.4;*/
    background-color:  #BACDC7;
}
.containX, .container {
    width: 61.875em;
    max-width:990px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin:0 auto; ///used for problem solving, not on original.
    padding: 0;
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en-GB">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
** GAP APPEAR HERE **
<div class="containX" id="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
/** Google analytics stuff only ***/
</script>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" style="display:none;">
<span itemprop="image">http://www.southwoldluxuryholidayhomes.co.uk/images/head1.jpg</span>
<span itemprop="name">Far View Holiday Homes Southwold</span>
<span itemprop="description">Far View are a high quality 4 star experience, with a Gold Award from Visit England. These Self-catering apartments overlook Southwold Common, on the Suffolk Heritage Coast.</span>
</div>
  <div class="header" >
```

EDIT:
I knew it was something silly that I missed, but for future readers - **check the `top-margin` CSS of *all* lower page elements!!**

Comment: If your question was answered, please check mark an answer as correct :)

Comment: haha, yes yes, but I have to wait  ten minutes or so - patience @saadq !!

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't know there was a time constraint :p

Comment: Questions have a time limit to be marked as answered only after ten minutes. I have now marked yours as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect with Chrome dev tools,  you can see that there is margin being applied to the `h1` in the `.header`. Removing that margin fixed it for me.

Put this in your CSS:

```
.header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks saadq, any idea why Firebug wasn't picking this up as an influencing factor?

Comment: After checking with Firebug, you can see this line of code in the `.header h1`: margin: 0.6em auto 0. The 0.6em is the amount of margin-top that is being applied currently.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the margin on the site now, cheers for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is being caused by the `H1` in the header. To fix,

```
.header h1 {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The h1 tag inside immediately inside of your header div has a margin top of 1.em... This is what is pushing your content down

Answer (score 1):

style rule `margin-top: 0.6em;` for selector `.header h1` at http://www.southwoldholidayhomes.com/css/stylesdw2.css line 73